# A question about $ y' = \frac{-x^3y}{(x^2+y^2+1)^2} $.

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

Given the differential equation: $ y' = \frac{-x^3y}{(x^2+y^2+1)^2} $, I need to prove that if $y(x)$ is a solution for the equation, then $y$ is an even function. thus, what can we say about the domain of the solutions of the equation?

I would appreciate any kind of directing how to solve this question, I still have no initial breakthrough to start solving it. any suggestions?

Comment: As a start, consider showing that if $y(x)$ is a solution, then so will $y(-x)$ be a solution, provided of course that $y$ is defined on the entire real line.

Answer (score 3):

Let $y(x)$ be a solution in the interval $(-a,a)$. Then, $y'(0)=0$

This implies the following function is $C^1$

$$g(x)=\begin{cases} y(x)\text{ if }x\in[0,a)\\y(-x)\text{ if }x\in(-a,0)\end{cases}$$

But

$$g'(x)=\begin{cases}y'(x)\text{ if }x\ge0\\-y'(-x)\text{ if }x<0\end{cases}={-x^3g(x)\over(x^2+g^2(x)+1)^2}$$

The existence and uniqueness theorem guarantees that $g=y$ on $(-a,a)$. A similar argument guarantees that the domain is always a symmetrical interval.

Now, to find the domains of maximal solutions, let's study the case $x\ge 0$

We can see that $y\equiv 0$ is the maximal solution for initial condition $y(0)=0$. So, a maximal solution is either always positive or always negative. Moreover, if $y(0)<0$, then $y$ is increasing; if $y(0)>0$, $y$ is decreasing. The theorem of escape from compact sets ensures that the domain of maximal solutions is therefore the whole $\mathbb{R}$.

**Added**: This proof actually needs an argument like copper.hat's in the first part, to justify the application of Cauchy-Lipschitz theorem.

Answer (score 2):

Let $f(y,x) = \frac{-x^3y}{(x^2+y^2+1)^2}$, then
${\partial f(y,x) \over \partial y} = { x^3 \over (1+x^2+y^2)^2} { 3 y^2-x^2 -1\over 1+x^2+y^2} $, and it is not too hard to see that ${\partial f(y,x) \over \partial y}$ is bounded on $\mathbb{R}^2$, hence $f$ satisfies a uniform
Lipschitz condition in $y$. In particular, there is a solution defined on
$\mathbb{R}$ passing through any point $(x_0,y_0)$, and any such solution is unique.

Show that $x \mapsto y(x)$ and $x \mapsto y(-x)$ satisfy the same differential equation.